# Как правильно употреблять:

Tags: склонение

«правительство Меркурий» или «правительство Меркурия»?

Comment: Непонятно, что это за правительство такое.

Comment: Такого лучше не употреблять. Вообще.

Answer (score -1):

Смотря в каком случае. Если это название фирмы, то правительство Меркурий, а если мы говорим о каком-то сказочном царстве, то второй вариант. Мне это так видится.